# Is there a way to rename an Xcode 4 scheme?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I've been looking all over Xcode for this, but I can't find any place that allows you to rename an existing scheme in Xcode 4. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 292, accepted):

You need to click on the scheme button, then hit "Manage Schemes".  Once you do so, you'll have a window like this:

[image]

Select the scheme you want to change, and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Now the scheme name will be editable, and you can change it to your hearts desire.  Then hit <kbd>Return</kbd> again to save it.

Comment: Apple docs link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Building/Building.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH9-SW26

Comment: @VinceYuan: Although return is easier, a very slow double click also does work.

Comment: @jheriko: i swear, it's not intuitive at all. however, i do notice that once I learn & remember something, it's convenient enough...

Answer (score 36):

A slow double click also does the job.

Comment: It's a bit like Finder behaviour in that a fast double click opens the items and a slow one allows renaming.

Comment: it's actually a single click on the name once it's already selected

Comment: Click once to select, then, later click again to edit. Great!

Answer (score 2):

Click once to select it. Then again click on selected title to get to edit mode.