# Duplicating an Xcode 4 Project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Basically I want to make an independent copy of my Xcode project and all of my files. How can I do this? I'm researching graphing frameworks and I want to use the same UI for each.

Comment: What’s wrong with simply copying the project folder including all the files?

Answer (score 24):

Seconding [@zoul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17279/zoul)'s comment, this can be accomplished in Xcode 4.5 with four steps.

1. In Finder, duplicate the project folder. Do not update the `.xcodeproj` file name.
2. In Xcode, rename the project. Accept the proposed changes.
3. Still in Xcode, rename the scheme in "Manage Schemes".
4. In `Info.plist`, rename your Bundle identifier.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346767/is-there-a-way-to-rename-an-xcode-4-scheme for how to rename a scheme (it's a bit of a trick to discover).

Comment: To rename the project: Click the project name in the Project Navigator (left-side pane).

Comment: I don't know if this is Xcode 5 thing but the Bundle identifier (in the project settings) changed automatically. (probably after renaming something)

Answer (score 1):

Few months ago, I had the need to create a different applications with the same source code.
I didn't wanted to copy the full directory, so I came up with a procedure that allowed me to mantain the source code in one place and create many different apps based on the same source code.

My procedure is the following:

- duplicate the target to make a new target and change the name to the new name
- change the name of the product and info.plist in the build options (select the new target and click info button), make sure this is for All Configurations
- rename the info.plist file created at the duplication to  "newnameInfo".plist (click on the file and then info button and pick the target)
- add icon.png to the resources for the specific target.
- change the name of the icon
- in the NewnameInfo.plist change the icon name to icon_xxx and the bundle identifier com.yourdomain.newname
- in language/other flags you can have a flag to check at the code.
- create a new APP_ID in the iOS Provisional Portal
- if APN is used, configure the APN BEFORE creating the development profile
- create a new development & distribution (ad-hoc or appstore)
- in Target (info) choose the right profile for the code sign

I hope this helps.

--nnahum

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project folder.  Right click on it.  Select "duplicate".

Is there something you want to achieve that this doesn't accomplish?

Comment: Yeah, the thing with doing that is that the duplicated project still references files in the older project. If I change something in my new project, it changes it in the old project as well. I can de-reference all of the files from inside XCode, and then drag in the files from the new folder, but this takes a while because I can't just click and drag the root folder in (it gives me import errors because it's trying to import indexing files and such which XCode doesn't allow, so it just doesn't import anything).

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste your project folder. Open the new folder and open the Xcode project file. Select the project name in the "Project Navigator" on the left side and then in "File Inspector" on the right hand side, change the name of the project under Identity and Type.

That way you will have a duplicate project with two different names.

Hope this helps!