# Guide to renaming files and projects in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, refactoring, xcode5

A month or so ago, I came across a very comprehensive and apparently highly-regarded step by step guide to refactoring, and renaming files and projects in `Xcode`. I thought for sure I had bookmarked it, but evidently not. I've done several searches for it and came up empty.

Can someone please point me toward it? I know similar questions have been asked and answered, but the particular post I'm looking for seemed to be regarded by many as the definitive guide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's the post I was looking for:

[Duplicate and rename Xcode project & associated folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744319/duplicate-and-rename-xcode-project-associated-folders)

And here is an update testing this process in Xcode 5:

http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-rename-an-app-in-xcode-4-5/

Many thanks to those who replied!

Answer (score 1):

You can use refactor feature of `Xcode` :-

[image] and rename class.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just press return on the file name which you need to rename and then change it..

Comment: I hope i will help you to rename files in XCODE