# Why am I getting the following errors after converting my project to swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, error-handling, swift3

After converting my project to swift 3 in the latest Xcode beta release, I am getting a slew of '... is missing from working copy' errors for various files within my project, even though they are present in the project navigator. Here is a shot of a couple of the errors:

[image]

What can I do to resolve these errors?

Comment: This looks more like a problem with your version control. Did you have a look at similar questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338428/xcode-issue-file-xxx-png-is-missing-from-working-copy-at-project-building, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292291/missing-file-warnings-showing-up-after-upgrade-to-xcode-4?

Comment: I have this error with just one .png file. Problem is this file is where it should be, git doesn't have any problem with that - only xcode. If it'd try to delete this file then instead of warning it'd have an actual error.