# How to move Core Data name.xcdatamodel from one folder to another?

Tags: ios, core-data

It should be quite simple, i have created single view application with code data checked. It created `name.xcdatamodel` file for me. App development has progressed further and I want to move all model related files to model folder. I created model folder, moved `name.xcdatamodel` to it, added it to project.

It should be simple, expect compiler / linker is warning me:

> oldLocation/name.xcdatamodeld/name.xcdatamodel/contents: warning:
>   Missing file: oldLocation/name.xcdatamodeld/name.xcdatamodel/contents
>   is missing from working copy
>
> oldLocation/name.xcdatamodeld/.xccurrentversion: warning: Missing
>   file: oldLocation/name.xcdatamodeld/.xccurrentversion is missing from
>   working copy

This is really puzzling, i have gone through project settings to see, if there are any missing references that link to old location, but could not find any.

What is the deal here?

Comment: Did you check out the topics about "missing from working copy" like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338428/xcode-issue-file-xxx-png-is-missing-from-working-copy-at-project-building?

Comment: yup, nothing helps, plus this is really easy to reproduce, just move model to different folder, and then add it to project.

Comment: Did you check the Location and Full Path entry in the File inspector? Maybe they are the problem.

Comment: commit your current copy on source control repository you use, all missing file warnings will get cleaned

Answer (score 2):

This usually occurs because the source control does not recognise the location change.

If you are using git just git rm on those files in the old location.
Similarly for svn use svn rm.

Refresh status and the warning should be gone.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode warns you of missing files in your local (Git) work-space. This seems to be a new "Feature" in Xcode8.

To get rid of the warning, simply commit your changes.

Answer (score 1):

You should check in your target's `Build Phases`, if the `Copy Bundle Resources` one has still a reference to the old file...