# Duplicating Xcode 6.0 project

Tags: ios, xcode, finder

I want to duplicate my Xcode project since I need to do a lot of copies with slightly changes, but every time I try o copy it, It lose a lot of Constraints in Storyboard (even some controls disappear), I tried this

[Duplicate and rename Xcode project & associated folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744319/duplicate-and-rename-xcode-project-associated-folders)

but is in Xcode 4 and is not working for me

EDIT: In my Identity it said that the location is absolute and I can't change it (it is in gray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first of all its always going to transfer.
So please check to see if the references have been removed and if they have just drag and drop them into the file area.
if it does not work you should copy the files from original project, and use them to create a new file to make up for the missing files.

Hope this helps have a good day! :)