# Regenerating the Bridging-Header and -Swift.h files after project name change

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

I have previously built a Keyboard extension project that has components of both Swift and Objective C. I'd like to built a new Keyboard app based on my previous app, with the simple goal of changing the name, keyboard UI and some keyboard mechanics.

I followed the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744319/duplicate-and-rename-xcode-project-associated-folders) on duplicating and renaming an XCode Project. I even managed to get the project to compile after changing the Bundle IDs (for both the container app and the underlying keyboard). However, because of the name of the **Targets** have now changed, I am get the error that the following files:

```
#import "NewNameContainerApp-Swift.h"
#import "NewNameContainerApp-Bridging-Header.h"
```

cannot be found (these errors persist despite me manually changing `OldNameContainerApp-Bridging-Header.h` to `NewNameContainerApp-Bridging-Header.h`. It seems that the project has not regenerated a new set of bridging header and `-Swift.h` files matching the names of my new target.

My question is - is there a way to force XCode to regenerate a new set of these files? And if not, where do I find `OldNameContainerApp-Swift.h` so I can manually change it to `NewNameContainerApp-Swift.h`?

Thanks!

Comment: Check in your build settings and define's module.

Answer (score 2):

Check in your applications `Define-Module` in the build section. Update it to your latest project name. To find it easily just search for `Defines-Module` and see if it needs updating. If it is updated try cleaning your project or deleting your `Derived Data`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Define Module is set to "Yes" in the new app, and Derived Data has been deleted, but unfortunately the issue persists.

Comment: Is there a snapshot of your project before the change? Usualy with changing project names xcode would create a snapshot of your project. If you just wanted to change the name of the app then you can do so in the info.plist.

Comment: That's indeed true, and good point. I am actually creating a whole new app, and therefore had to change the Bundle ID as well, which initially caused the problem. I managed to figure out a workaround where the container app's bundle ID was modified, but the extension bundle ID kept part of the original app's name, and this allowed it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found no way to force Xcode to regenerate these files. Removing them just causes builds to fail. The only reliable method is to do a clean build, or removed DerivedData and rebuild (effectively the same solution).

When renaming an Objective-C/Swift mixed app, the following additional changes have to be performed for a successful build.

The Swift to Objective-C header file depends on the module name:

```
<ModuleName>-Swift.h
```

So if the Module name changes, you need to change the `import` in your code. In build settings search for `Product Module Name` to find the module name that is being used.

The Objective-C to Swift bridging header name depends on the build setting `Objective-C Bridging Header`. Check the Xcode target build settings and modify to match your new name.