# Making a copy of allegro file in Xcode

Tags: xcode6, allegro5

So I am experimenting with Allegro and I am happily creating graphic primitives but I want to make different allegro files! So I tried to make a duplicate template with all the allegro libraries because it would be a pain to do it each time. I also tried to copy and paste the folder that successfully runs and that doesn't work either. I keep getting this error

> Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I go to the build phases and link all the allegro frameworks together and nothing changes.

Here is the error message

> Ld /Users/catsonmars/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/okWhatsWrong-gfhonrkyrxwrsrcyurtfmfyijtqm/Build/Products/Debug/MyGame.app/Contents/MacOS/MyGame normal x86_64
>       cd "/Users/catsonmars/Documents/Programs/third try for allegro"
>       export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.10
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -L/Users/catsonmars/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/okWhatsWrong-gfhonrkyrxwrsrcyurtfmfyijtqm/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/catsonmars/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/okWhatsWrong-gfhonrkyrxwrsrcyurtfmfyijtqm/Build/Products/Debug -F/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/catsonmars/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/okWhatsWrong-gfhonrkyrxwrsrcyurtfmfyijtqm/Build/Intermediates/third\ try\ for\ allegro.build/Debug/MyGame.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MyGame.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/../Frameworks -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Allegro-5.1 -framework AllegroAcodec-5.1 -framework AllegroAudio-5.1 -framework AllegroColor-5.1 -framework AllegroDialog-5.1 -framework AllegroFont-5.1 -framework AllegroImage-5.1 -framework AllegroMain-5.1 -framework AllegroMemfile-5.1 -framework AllegroPhysfs-5.1 -framework AllegroPrimitives-5.1 -framework AllegroTTF-5.1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/catsonmars/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/okWhatsWrong-gfhonrkyrxwrsrcyurtfmfyijtqm/Build/Intermediates/third\ try\ for\ allegro.build/Debug/MyGame.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MyGame_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/catsonmars/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/okWhatsWrong-gfhonrkyrxwrsrcyurtfmfyijtqm/Build/Products/Debug/MyGame.app/Contents/MacOS/MyGame
>
> duplicate symbol __al_mangled_main in:
>       /Users/catsonmars/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/okWhatsWrong-gfhonrkyrxwrsrcyurtfmfyijtqm/Build/Intermediates/third try for allegro.build/Debug/MyGame.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main1.o
>       /Users/catsonmars/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/okWhatsWrong-gfhonrkyrxwrsrcyurtfmfyijtqm/Build/Intermediates/third try for allegro.build/Debug/MyGame.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
>   ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I went to this topic and it didn't help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744319/duplicate-and-rename-xcode-project-associated-folders

Comment: I think a better solution might be to start over every time... I do it... and those are a lot of errors