# Xcode - Save Project As

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

I have created a new project in Swift and given it some random name.

Now, I want to save this project with another name.

I cannot find any "Save as" anywhere.

How do I do save an existing project as a new project with a different name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicate and rename Xcode project & associated folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744319/duplicate-and-rename-xcode-project-associated-folders)

Comment: Thanks Jal :)  Is there any chance, that I could contact You directly somehow ?  It's regarding an answer You gave in a different question I found here ? Can't find any way to send You a message...

Comment: Comment on the answer in question and we can start a conversation about it.

Comment: Hi JAL, tried to do just that, but got a message about me not asking further questions in that thread :(

Comment: So I will post a new question and then maybe You can join there

Comment: That's fine, or post the URL to the question here.

Comment: Here is the link for the other question:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666870/autoplay-videos-not-from-youtube