# Duplicating Xcode project - Renaming bridging header

Tags: xcode, swift, bridging-header

I followed the advice found in [Duplicate and rename Xcode project & associated folders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17744319/2108547)
and it worked, except for the bridging header which still needs the old project name as the prefix. How can I change the bridging header name to correspond to the current project name?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly but if you would like to just rename the Bridging Header file itself you can do that by finding it in the Project navigator, click `enter` on it and then type the new name.

[image]

If however you would like to change the reference when building to point at your new Bridging Header, then you can change that by going to `Build Settings` for your project, select the proper target and then the easiest is to do a search for `Bridging Header`. You should now be able to alter the path and name of where your Bridging Header is located.

[image]

Hope that answers your question