# Changing the name of main folder in Xcode project

Tags: xcode

This is not the first time I've had trouble with this and I suspect not the last time either.  Despite having learned many frameworks inside out I still find the organizational structure of a simple xcode project elusive.  I simply wanted to retitle a project from CATouchSynth to ABTouchSynth.  A while ago I discovered that if you click on the Project folder in project navigator and than change the name in the Identity and Type section it will rename many of the relevant files and directories to the new name.  However, there is one main folder inside the folder on your computer that doesn't change and still has the old name.  I could see no way to change this folder name through Xcode and so I renamed it manually from finder.  This turned all of my source files and assets red so I manually "relinked" them in xcode and they are now non-red and seemingly linked with the newly named folder.  However I am getting several compile-time errors talking about the old folder name but I have no clue what Xcode is referring too.  The errors look like this

[image: errors!]

It seemed as if derived data was an issue so I deleted the derived data folder from Xcode and I still get these errors.  Has anyone experienced this before and what can I do to ressurrect my project?

Comment: Renaming step by step: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17744320/2108547

Answer (score 5):

Note: Before doing any changes do backup your project folder. This is seriously recommended.

Follow the steps below to rename the source folder of your project –

1. Close XCode.
2. Rename the Source Folder.
3. Right click the project bundle **.xcodeproj** file and select **“Show Package Contents”** from the context menu. Open the **.pbxproj** file with any text editor (Xcode).
4. **This step should be done with extreme caution.** Search and replace any occurrence of **the original folder name** with the new folder name.
5. Save and Close the file.
6. Open XCode project.

Answer (score 1):

The error is happening at build time during the compile phase, so you will have to go into the app target's Compile Sources build phase, remove all those *.m* files, and add them again.

[image]

Comment: But basically what you did was just silly. "I could see no way to change this folder name through Xcode and so I renamed it manually from finder" You should never have done that. That folder name is hard-coded through the build settings, as you have discovered. What on earth do you care anyway? It's not part of your app in any way; it's not the project folder; it's just an internal folder. You should have left it alone.