# Getting error after changing project folder name in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When I created my project, I called it "Project1". Then, later I've changed it to "Project2" from the Xcode. I changed all "Project1" to "Project2", but now, when I compile my project, it looks for files in `Project2/Project1/myFile.swift` and I get the next error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/myusername/Copy/Projects/Project2/Project1/myFile.swift'
```

I need to make that it will look at

```
/Users/myusername/Copy/Projects/Project2/myFile.swift
```

without `Project1` in the path.

How can I solve this problem? Also, I changed from Xcode `Identity and Type` section `Location` of my project.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-ios-app?rq=1

Comment: @sschale I've already done it. It did not solve my problem

Comment: @JohnDoe close your xcode and reopen it try now

Comment: delete your dervied data and try once

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I did it, too. Nothing again

Comment: @KishoreKumar did it, too. Doesn't help

Comment: go to buildphase see is there any file missing @JohnDoe

Comment: @KishoreKumar no. There are no `red` files

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744319/duplicate-and-rename-xcode-project-associated-folders

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I get this error `CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler`. How can I fix it?

Comment: @JohnDoe in my case there are no red files ,but miss path files are there ,check your library search path and all paths

Answer (score 1):

Today I had the same problem when I renamed the folder containing the Xcode project and some parent folders of it.

In my case there where a .swift file shown with it's name in red in the list of files of Xcode (Navigator area). I think that this means that Xcode was not capable to find that file.

I selected that file (actually it's not a real file but a representation of it).

Then, in the File Inspector (Utility area), I clicked on the Folder icon and chose the file on Finder.

[image]

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming projects in xcode in one of the most annoying things in iOS development. I assume you want to rename your app. I faced this problem once and figured out a simple, clean way to do it.

1. Go back to the point where everything worked.
2. Open project in xcode and click on the project icon in the project structure( first file)
3. Go to the info tab
4. Search for `Bundle Name`. Most probably it will automatically be set to `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` which is a shell variable that will set your app name the same as the project name.
5. Set it to whatever you want your app name to be
6. Done

**Note :**

- If you use `custom URL Schemes` this *might* produce an error when redirecting.

  **ALWAYS** use `git` or some other SVN in your projects. This will come in handy in this kind of situations

Answer (score -1):

1. Change you folder name in you finder "Project1" to "Project2"
2. Remove "myFile.swift" file from project (copy on Desktop)
3. Restart Xcode. Copy "myFile.swift" in project select "Copy file to folder" hope this will help.

Comment: It's a long way! So, if I have 100 files, I need to do this process 100 times?

Comment: possibly you didn't rename you project right way use apple docs

Comment: I get this error: `CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler` Can I fix it?