# Duplicate Xcode project uses old project_dir

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-workspace

I am trying to create a duplicate of my Xcode workspace. I have made a duplicate folder in Finder. Let's call the original Project_v1 and the duplicate Project_v2.

When I open Xcode in order to deal with all the additional issues i notice that my location/fullpath are both /Users/abcd/Desktop/Abcd/Project_v1/Project.xcodeproj (Relative to Group) even though I opened Project_v2 folder.

When I watch online tutorials about this the path is always the new path. If I choose Project_v2 by clicking the little folder icon under Identity and Type then my entire structure in left pane changes (folders go blue not yellow, project app icon turns to a folder etc).

How is it even possible that my project contained within Project_v2 is referencing v1? And how do I safely change it to v2 whilst keeping everything else correct?

Comment: Related: [Duplicate and rename Xcode project & associated folders](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17744320/2108547)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. As mentioned, I have looked at all these and would happily use them but the issue is that my project is referencing the old folder which is not what tutorials suggest is normal

Comment: And now I cannot even get xCode to open any duplicate created - keeps crashing 'unexpectedly' so now I guess I've really damaged something

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically I just have to keep ditching copies and starting again using a different name until somehow things kick in.

For some reason when I try to change the path of the project in the File Inspector it randomly either allows me to select the xcodeproj file or not. If it does I am ok. If it doesn't there's nothing I can do but start again.

The key is being able to change this path but seems random whether allowed to do so.

EDIT:
Seems the only way to be able to sort this out is to change the projects path to Absolute, choose the folder Project_v2 (not the xcodeproj file as this isn't possible), then change back to Relative to Group and then actually choose the xcodeproj file as the intended location.