# At Xcode, how to change what is seen between "Run" "Stop" buttons, and "iPhone 5.1 Simulator"

Tags: xcode

I have changed my project name / product name, but I still see the old project name between the "Run" "Stop" buttons, and "iPhone 5.1 Simulator".

How do I change it? How many instances does the project name have in different locations?

Comment: Here's the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346767/is-there-a-way-to-rename-an-xcode-4-scheme

Answer (score 0):

That name is referred to as the scheme name. Assuming you are using xcode 4, you should be able to change it by clicking on the 'Product -> Manage Schemes' menu. You should see your scheme name in the list and easily rename it.