# How to change the name of the active scheme in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, configuration

I managed to change my project name, but how do I change the name displayed  directly to the left of "iOS Simulator"?

Comment: [i think best one described. a graphical view][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5346944/1893753

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to rename an Xcode 4 scheme?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346767/is-there-a-way-to-rename-an-xcode-4-scheme)

Comment: Your screenshot is not showing...

Answer (score 534, accepted):

This is in the Xcode documentation available from the "Help" menu. Choose "Help" > "Xcode Help", then enter "rename scheme" to find it. Here are the steps:

1. Choose "Edit Scheme" from the "Product" menu.
2. Click on the "Manage Schemes…" button
3. Select the scheme whose name you wish to change
4. Press the "Return" key

It will select the name of the scheme and allow you to edit it.

Comment: that worked in XCode 8 and I find the Xcode help so generally unhelpful that I never even thought to look it up.  thanks for the helpful answer.

Comment: Note that you need to literally press "Return", double-clicking takes you to the wrong place.

Answer (score 11):

XCODE 9:

> **Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme**

[image]

Or simply click and hold left mouse button on your project icon (on the right from the run button) and select **Edit scheme**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If your XCode is version 13 you can Duplicate the Schema > Set the new name > Choose the old name schema from the list and press the Minus button at the bottom to delete.

That's the only way I could achieve this since the Schema Manager doesn't let me rename directly from the Scheme List pressing Return.

It's weird but worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode click these keys:

1. click "Command" + "Shift" + "<"
2. click "Manage Schemas..."
3. tap your project name and then click "return" key
4. edit to what you want

That's it.

Answer (score -1):

you change from the help menu on the hand you can find the product menu choose scheme and edit the name or you can add new one.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFlWx.png)

Answer (score -5):

You can remove them, then add them again with a new name.

Answer (score -9):

The best way is to duplicate the scheme that works, but with the wrong name, use the new name, then delete the bad one.

Hit the gear-button near the plus-minus buttons new the lower left corner.

Comment: Sorry but that is an awful way