# 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found in RNFIRMessaging.h

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

In Podfile, when using `use_frameworks!` globally to integrate swift pods in my react native project, Firebase pod files starts giving error 
Firebase pods:-

```
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

Error :-

> 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found in RNFIRMessaging.h

issue gets resolved when comment out `use_frameworks!` in podfile but then i am unable to install swift pods. also tried :`modular_headers => true` for specific swift pods but pod file is not installing.

Swift pods i am trying to install are :-

```
 pod 'Kite-Print-SDK'
 pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK/Core'
```

please help me out to resolve this issue..

Comment: Did you try to pod deintegrate and then pod install again? It can solve a lot of problems. Regards.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, But i have already tried still issue is not disappearing.

Comment: I think this solution can help. please check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57304947/8612340

Answer (score 1):

Please consider check at edit scheme ->Build -> check if Find Implicit Dependencies. if not enable please enable it and rerun. [image]

Answer (score -1):

I actually had a similar problem,
my solution was to change the code manually wherever there was that error.

change

```
import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>
```

to

```
import <FirebaseCore.h>
```