# Firebase_core, flutter build errors

Tags: xcode, firebase, flutter, cocoapods, dart-pub

I've been stuck for days now with build errors for flutter core. This is iOS build, haven't tried android so far since it doesn't matter if i cant get the iOS to run :)

```
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           40.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    While building module 'firebase_core' imported from /Users/mikael.melander/Documents/development/swift-it/storyspot/flutter/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:34:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from /Users/mikael.melander/Documents/development/swift-it/storyspot/flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/firebase_core/firebase_core.framework/Headers/firebase_core-umbrella.h:13:
    In file included from /Users/mikael.melander/Documents/development/swift-it/storyspot/flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/firebase_core/firebase_core.framework/Headers/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h:11:
    /Users/mikael.melander/Documents/development/swift-it/storyspot/flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/firebase_core/firebase_core.framework/Headers/FLTFirebasePlugin.h:9:9: error: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'firebase_core.FLTFirebasePlugin': 'Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/Public/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' [-Werror,-Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module]
    #import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>
            ^
    1 error generated.
    /Users/mikael.melander/Documents/development/swift-it/storyspot/flutter/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:34:9: fatal error: could not build module 'firebase_core'
    #import <firebase_core/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
    2 errors generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
```

I've tried flutter channel, master, dev and stable.
I've tried updating the plugins as much as I can.
I've done flutter clean, removed pubspec.lock, podfile.lock, pods, deleted DerivedData etc.

Pubspec file:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  rxdart: ^0.25.0
  http: ^0.12.2
  google_maps_flutter: 1.1.1
  location: ^3.0.2
  dio: 3.0.10
  fluster: 1.1.2
  flutter_cache_manager: 2.1.1
  carousel_slider: 2.2.1
  cached_network_image: 2.5.0
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  intl: 0.16.1
  multi_image_picker: 4.7.12
  font_awesome_flutter: 8.8.1
  get_it: 4.0.4
  get: ^3.26.0
  introduction_screen: ^1.0.9
  smart_select: ^3.0.3
  flutter_google_places: 0.2.8
  shimmer: ^1.1.1
  google_fonts: ^1.1.0
  path_provider: ^1.6.14
  progress_button: ^0.0.2
  email_validator: ^1.0.5
  device_info: ^0.4.2+7
  audioplayers: 0.16.2
  url_launcher: ^5.7.10
  google_sign_in: 4.5.3
  uni_links: ^0.4.0
  share: ^0.6.4+5
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.4
  dio_http_cache: ^0.2.8
  permission_handler: ^5.1.0+2
  devicelocale: ^0.3.3
  firebase_analytics: ^7.0.1
  flutter_sound:
    path: /Users/mikael.melander/Documents/development/swift-it/storyspot/tau/flutter_sound
  sortedmap: ^0.4.2+1
  latlong: ^0.6.1
  flutter_svg: ^0.19.1
  sign_in_with_apple: ^2.5.4
  keyboard_visibility: 0.5.6
  image_cropper: ^1.3.1
  flutter_bounce: ^1.0.8
  flutter_document_picker: ^4.0.1
  flutter_email_sender: ^4.0.0
  firebase_core: 0.7.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

***I'm doing a custom fork of flutter_sound, but no dependencies have changed. Running latest 7.7.0+1***

In this example i've added the firebase_core: 0.7.0, i've tried without it as well, but the only matching for this exact config is 0.7.0 otherwise it's a mismatch of dependencies.

Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.1.0-11.0.pre.145, on macOS 11.2.1 20D75 darwin-x64, locale en-SE)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

As said, i've tried stable and dev as well.

Any ideas? I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else, this solved my problem, although not a long term solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65673063/12208709