# New project fails using SwiftUI, XCode 12 and Catalina

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, macos-catalina, xcode12

I'm trying to create a new XCode project, plain brand new and I can run it on the simulator, but on the canvas it says: `Cannot preview in this file - active scheme does not build this file`
If on top of that I start adding macOS support, it says:

`'appName' is annotated with @main and must provide a main static function of type () -> Void or () throws -> Void.` It also says:

`Cannot find type 'App' in scope`

`Cannot find type 'Scene' in scope`

Regarding mac support I was reading there is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63971819/ios-xcode-12-0-swift-5-appdelegate-is-annotated-with-main-and-must-provide-a), even though I tried and the error remains.

As for the active scheme, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58416469/cannot-preview-in-this-file-active-scheme-does-not-build-this-file-swiftui-o), but doesn't help. I mean... there is only 1 scheme in a new project and it's selected automatically

I would assume a plain hello world project would work, what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the macOS support is what Asperi mentioned, on Catalina has problems supporting mac on XCode 12.

As for the new project failing, I found that if I press `Cmd + Opt + P`, it would build it on the Canvas fine. I had tried clicking "Try again" on the canvas which I would assume is the same and didn't work. You don't need to delete the file and create a new one nor select any target since it's a new project and the target is selected automatically.
Also the `@Main` doesn't have to be changed to run on iOS and iPad, for macOS support just wait until Big Sur releases.

Answer (score 3):

SwiftUI 2.0 on macOS is available **only** starting from **Big-Sur macOS 11.0**

```
@available(iOS 14.0, macOS 11.0, tvOS 14.0, watchOS 7.0, *)
public protocol App {
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Maybe I should edit the title then, I have Catalina, I was assuming it was SwiftUI 2.0, the thing is that as soon as I create a new project it fails. I do have XCode 12 tho. I'm updated XCode and everything, I don't understand why a new project gives this error

Comment: Yes, Xcode 12 allows to create new macOS project with SwiftUI 2.0, but you cannot target it for and run it on Catalina. For Catalina you should create new project with SwiftUI UIKit life-cycle and use only SwiftUI 1.0 API.

Comment: I see, that's probably why. So if I create a `SwiftUI App` life cycle now on Catalina will I be able to run macOS support  when Big Sur release? It's kind of a dumb question but I want to make sure.

Comment: Yes, it will, but if you're going to develop for macOS 11 it is better to develop on macOS 11. ))

Comment: new Swift/Xcode coder here and the start is pretty rough :D i understand what you mean @Asperi, but no idea how to implement that Catalina/SwiftUI 1.0 start. any help possible?

Comment: argh, of course found it after posting. need to create a new app with the AppDelegate life-cycle option rather than SwiftUI. was hidden in the dropdown :))